# Keycloak Identity Broker - Possible to create invalid User-Accounts

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

When using Keycloak as an Identity Broker there seems to be an issue with some usernames. Default behavior of Keycloak is that when some info (username/email/firstname/lastname) is missing the "Update Account Information" is displayed.

So far so good. The issue though is that you can actually save an invalid username that way, e.g. (asd/fölkj - notice the slash). Now I basically created a broken user that can no longer be modified, not even using the Admin-UI:
[[image: Screenshot from ADMIN API1]
You can't save it like that because the username is invalid, but you can't change the username since it is read-only.

This seems to be a bug. The bigger issue for me though is that the IDP we are connecting to does not return the email-claim (otherwise I could use that as username too). It only returns a "sub" and since sadly this DOES contain slashes the account is broken if the user does not pick another username. I took a look at the "UsernameTemplateMapper", but they seem a bit limited. Is there any way to just remove all slashes from the "sub"-claim and STILL use it as default username?

Comment: From the IDP do you get the preferred_username claim? You can extend the Keycloak code and create your own UsernameTemplateMapper that does the removal of '/'

Comment: Btw what happen if you in the Keycloak Realm > login set edit username to on?

Comment: THanks for the tip, with the UsernameTemplateMapper I will try it out.
When i enable "edit username" at least an admin can recover the account, but it's still possible to create an invalid account for the user. I created a bug on Github for that.